# Повышение порядка значения

Tags: c++

Как можно из 4 и 2 получить 400, ни за что более не цепляясь?

---

На основе следующего прототипа создайте функцию mag(), повышающую порядок значения переменной num до того уровня, который задан переменной order:

```
void mag (long &num, long order);
```

Например, если переменная num равна 4, а переменная order равна 2, то после выполнения функции mag() переменная num должна стать равной 400. Напишите демонстрационную программу, показывающую, что функция работает.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, надо умножать num на 10, пока оно не лежит в диапазоне [10^order, 10^(order + 1)).

Comment: @dzhioev, спасибо.

Comment: Может просто умножить `num` на `10 ^ order` ?

Comment: ...ну или (что то же самое) `order` раз умножить на 10 при положительном `order`, или `-order` разделить на 10 при отрицательном. (Что делать при `order == 0`, остаётся в качестве упражнения.)

Comment: @avp, ну не знаю, написано "повышающую порядок значения переменной num *до* того уровня". Кажется, что в итоге мы должно получить число порядка order.

Comment: @dzhioev, вполне возможно. Формулировка, какая-то неоднозначная.

Comment: >Не представляю, как можно из 4 и 2 получить 400, ни за что более не цепляясь.

Написать между ними e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить такое решение: *Если правильно понял задачу.*

Для всех случаев. Если есть отрицательный порядок, или нужно кидать исключения или ставить максимальное значение типа, при его превышении.

```
//#define USE_EXCEPTION  // выбрасывать исключение при превышении значения long
#define NEGATIVE_ORDER // при отрицательном порядке уходит в минус, иначе значение 0

void mag(long &num, long order)
{
if(order > 0)
{
for(long i = 0; i < order; i++)
{
if(((long long)num * 10) > LONG_MAX){num=LONG_MAX; 
#ifdef USE_EXCEPTION
throw(std::exception("Превышено максимальное значение LONG 2147483647"));
#endif
break;}else{num *= 10;}
}
}

if(order < 0)
{
bool negative = false;
for(long i = 0; i > order; i--)
{

#ifdef NEGATIVE_ORDER
if(negative==true || (num / 10) <= 0)
#else
if(5<3)
#endif
{
negative = true;
if(((long long)num * 10) > LONG_MAX)
{
num=LONG_MAX;
#ifdef USE_EXCEPTION
throw(std::exception("Превышено минимальное значение LONG -2147483647"));
#endif
break;
}else
{
num = num * 10;
}
}
else
{
num = num / 10;
}

}
if(negative)
{
num = -num;
}
}

}

int main()
{
std::system("chcp 1251");

try
{
{// 
long num = 214748364;
long order = 1;
mag(num,order);
std::cout << "\nmag=" << num;
}

{// переполнение
long num = 4;
long order = 30;
mag(num,order);
std::cout << "\nmag макс=" << num;
}

{
long num = 400;
long order = -2;
mag(num,order);
std::cout << "\nmag отрицательный=" << num;
}

{
long num = 400;
long order = -40;
mag(num,order);
std::cout << "\nmag мин=" << num;
}
}
catch(std::exception e)
{
std::cout << "\n\n#!#ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ#!#\a \n--" << e.what() << "--";
}

std::cout << "\n";
std::system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. А для отрицательных значений `order`?
2. Неплохо бы ещё сдетектировать переполнение.

Comment: 3. Переполнение в смысле исключение кидать? Или ставить макс значение?


А как при отрицательном порядке считать? 

order=-2 num = 4??


После первого деления на 10, num=0. В минус не хочет идти.

код обновил.

Comment: 3: я бы кидал исключение, а то как отличить законное макс. значение от незаконного? да и сообщать об ошибках надо так, чтобы на них нельзя было махнуть рукой.  
1: да, вы правы, возврат целого типа не рассчитан на деление, так что `order < 0` тоже должно быть ошибкой.

Comment: 3: тут для целого типа не удастся добится точного LONG_MAX. И можно сравнивать if(num==LONG_MAX){cout("превышен");}  Только если сама константа LONG_MAX будет иной. Например с такими данными:


LONG_MAX:
2147483640

значение num:
214748364

order: 1

Comment: 3: на мой вкус исключение всё же правильнее. иначе вызывающий имеет шанс забыть проверить значение. хотя это уже вопросы личных предпочтений, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

```
void mag(long &num,long order)
{
    for (; order; order--) {
        num=num*10;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    long x=4;
    mag(x, 2);
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```